# homebrew install for gfortran fails for xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4, homebrew, gfortran

I have xcode4.2 installed and because of that, I am unable to get gfortran installed via homebrew.

Here's the error:

```
calvin$ brew -v install gfortran
Homebrew 0.8
==> Downloading http://r.research.att.com/gfortran-lion-5666-3.pkg
/usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew 0.8 (Ruby 1.8.7-249; Mac OS X 10.7.2) http://r.research.att.com    /gfortran-lion-5666-3.pkg -o /Users/calvin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gfortran-4.2.4-5666.3.pkg
######################################################################## 100.0%^[[B
/usr/bin/xar -xf /Users/calvin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gfortran-4.2.4-5666.3.pkg 
mv *.pkg/Payload Payload.gz 
ls | grep -v Payload | xargs rm -r 
/usr/bin/gcc
Error: Currently the gfortran compiler provided by this brew is only supported
for:

  - XCode 3.1.4 on OS X 10.5.x
  - XCode 3.2.2/3.2.3 -- 4.0 on OS X 10.6.x
  - XCode 4.1 on OS X 10.7.x

The AppStore and Software Update can help upgrade your copy of XCode.
The latest version of XCode is also available from:

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html
rmdir: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.2.4-5666.3 (empty)
Error: Nothing was installed to /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.2.4-5666.3
```

How can I get this working (using xcode 4.2, downgrading my xcode 4.2 isn't really a good option) ?

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8173) at Homebrew.  Interesting that they use binaries instead of building the compiler themselves.

Comment: This works now as aforementioned GitHub issue 8173 is fixed.  Just successfully ran `brew install gfortran` in OSX10.7/XCode4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew in my experience is the worst option to obtain gfortran on OS X.

Did you try binaries from [this page](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/)?

Another option is [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). And you can also compile gfortran from sources by yourself. It's not that difficult with XCode 3. However the story might be different with XCode 4, because of the default LLVM-compiler.

Is there any specific reason to use the latest version of XCode for you? Try binaries first. I didn't test them with XCode 4 but... Let us know if you try.

Comment: You can also try the Lion binary from http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have switched back to using MacPorts to obtain gfortran and gcc44. Works like a charm.

Comment: I used the Lion binary mentioned by @JoshBleecherSnyder, but I also had to hand-edit the 0.7.2 source files with changes from  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/effa6f68